# Remove default theme styling in @mui v5

Tags: material-ui

When theming @mui v4.x I could remove some style by setting it to undefined:

```js
MuiCardHeader: {
    action: {
        flex: undefined,
        ...
    },
```

It seems to not work in v5.

What is the way to do it in v5?

Comment: How about overriding it with the [default value](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp#:~:text=Default%20value%3A-,0%201%20auto,-Inherited%3A)?

Comment: @NearHuscarl: This is a workaround I use. Much less elegant than in v4.

Comment: you can also use `flex: 'initial'`, it should be reset to the default value.

Comment: Looks like it's a jss feature. Once they moved to emotion it has gone

Comment: You can answer and accept your own question if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can still [override the props](https://mui.com/customization/theme-components/#global-style-overrides) but the shape of the Theme object is a bit different in v5: defaultProps and styleOverrides are set under the `components` key

```js
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiCardHeader: {
      styleOverrides: {
        action: {
          flex: undefined,
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: The question is regarding removal, not overriding. Setting flex to `undefined` does nothing (in v5 way of course)